# Update <input> value onchange

Tags: javascript, html

I have bunch of inputs like:

```html
<input />
<input />
<input />
```

and a button which ads extra input

```html
<button>Add Input</button>
```

> The issue is that when a user put the text in the input(s) and add
>   additional input afterwards (i.e. press `Add Input`) the entered text in old inputs disappears.

**JSFiddle**:

```html
<div id="inputs"></div>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('inputs').innerHTML += '<input /><br>'">Add Input</button>
```

---

So I decided to update `<input>` `value` attribute. I have tried with `onchange` but had no luck.

The code with errors and trials is super simple and looks like:

```
function change_value(el) {

 document.getElementById('some-id').value = el.value
}
```

```html
<input id="some-id" value="${this.value}" onchange="change_value(this)" />
```

Will be grateful for any suggestions about how to keep `<input value` up-to-date with user text.

Comment: `value="${this.value}"` What is this supposed to do? Why are you immediately setting the `val` back to where you got it from, here? `el.value = val`

Comment: Use onkeydown event. You could use the keyup and keypress events as well.

Comment: @Cerbrus this is just error and trial to access `this.value` variable. as well as setting variable back and forth. nevermind.

Comment: You just have one element, which should update itself just fine without any extra code. If you had two elements to be synchronized, we could help.

Comment: @Adder I've updated my question with the info what problem I am trying to solve

Comment: Where is the code that shows what happens on button click?

Comment: @Adder I've added JSFiddle to my post

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now.

Comment: I edited my previous answer, and answered your question - the input values stay, new input is added. You don't need to do tricks with the value, only use **appendChild** (with **createElement**) instead of **innerHTML**

Comment: @muka.gergely how did you do this? :) thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what content you want to update. You can find a snippet below, that works **oninput** and updates the **textContent** of a **span**.

```js
const input = document.getElementById('some-id')
const display = document.getElementById('updated')

input.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  display.textContent = this.value

})
```

```html
<input id="some-id" value="" /><br /><br />
<div>Updated value: <span id="updated"></span></div>
```

## EDIT

A new snippet may clear things up a bit.

```js
const btnAdd = document.getElementById('add')

btnAdd.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = "text";

  document.getElementById('inputs').appendChild(input)
})
```

```html
<div id="inputs"></div>

<button id="add">Add Input</button>
```

Use **createElement()** instead of **innerHTML**.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I just can't understand why inputed text not disappears in your edit :))  But in my jsfiddle it does :)

Comment: I think with **innerHTML** you update the whole HTML in the container (that describes the new **input** too, while with **appendChild** the newly created element is just appended to the node structure.

Comment: ah, make sense. thanks again for your help @muka.gergely. upvoted and marked as accepted answer.

Comment: Actually don't take my word for it - it's just what **I think** why it works... :) I've never actually researched the difference between these two techniques. But anyway - I'm happy that I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using innerHtml like this

```
document.getElementById('some-id').innerHtml instead of value
```

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is not possible this way, maybe with some tricks like with any change store the value and create new input with the new value or change the innerHtml, maybe it works.

Comment: I've updated my question with more details about what problem I am trying to solve